# Eclipse - Cannot install subclipse / subversive

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I am unable to install new plugins to eclipse (tried subclipse and subversive). Installing fails around 47/48 %. This happens with both Helios and Indigo. I tried installing via Help>Install New Software and Help>Eclipse Marketplace.

Errors in both versions are about the same:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,       
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Unable to read repository at
http://market.eclipsesource.com/dist/.sitestore/4f/4f5ba7f7716b8c0f63ef
9b74b0173826/../../../../artifacts/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.cor
e_1.6.17.jar. 

Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  http://market.eclipsesource.com
/dist/.sitestore/4f/4f     5ba7f7716b8c0f63ef9b74b0173826/../../../../artifacts/
plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc_1.3.0.jar.

Read timed out
```

I don't think it's my internet connection as I'm having no issues browsing the web and multiple tracert tests work fine. I have tried removing the sites from available software sites and tried setting Active Provider in network connects to both direct and native.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: what is the plugin version that you see at the marketplace dialog? also include the old version number of the plugins if they exist previously

Comment: The version is update_1.6.x - also happens when I use the 1.8.x link for the subversion website

Comment: If you check your Eclipse installation details, you should be able to find exact version numbers like:  Subclipse (Required) 1.6.18, Subversive SVN Connectors 2.2.2.I20110819-1700

Comment: another piece of information that is helpful, would be the update sites you are using for subclipse and subversive. I don't remember them being on market.eclipsesource.com

Comment: When I install from Help>Install New Software I use the link to subclipse provided on their website - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x From Eclipse Market Place I simply search for subclipse and click install ont he first result this link it gives is http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same issues and resolved with following steps:

1. Check all .jar files that are causing errors "Unable to read repository at..."and "Read timed out"
2. Manually download those .jar files
3. Manually put .jar to eclipse's "\plugins" folder
4. Again start installation
5. Won’t get error
6. You done.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to follow while Enable SVN in Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0):

Visit this link: http://subclipse.tigris.org/ to get the “Eclipse update site URL” for Subclipse plugin. As of now Feb 2019 its move to location - https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki

Here you can https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/

Basic Steps:

1. Help>Install New Software.
2. Click on Add - Give name:  Subversive
3. https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/
4. Install all the components, and accept the license.
5. Restart the eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Windows 7 / 64bit / Eclipse Java EE Juno SR1.

I got around the issue by installing Subversive via the Eclipse Marketplace rather than with "Install new Software" using the Eclipse Juno update site.

I had exactly the same problem with EGit and the above solved it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by downloading and installing subclipse locally, from here : http://subclipse.tigris.org/files/documents/906/49270/site-1.8.20.zip